# How to run CURL from AWK statement

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to compare two CSV which have file hash stored and trying to upload the file which has mismatch hash.
I'm however not able to run CURL from within AWK statement in the shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
internalurl=<internalURL>

awk -v internalurl=$internalurl 'BEGIN {
   FS = OFS = ","
}
NR == FNR {
   map[$1] = $2
   next
}
!($1 in map) || map[$1] != $2 {
   print $1

   #Upload the file to 
   system("curl -F "'fileData=@$(find download -type f -iname $1)'" -O --write-out "'uploaded %{size_upload} bytes returned status_code=|%{http_code}| in %{time_total}s.'" internalurl")
 
}' first.csv second.csv
```

In file data, I'm searching for a file from the directory 'download'. $1 returns the file name.

I'm getting below error around 'in'

I'm getting an error `"syntax error near unexpected token` in'" ->      `system("curl -F "'fileData=@$(find download -type f -iname $1)'" -O --write-out "'uploaded %{size_upload} bytes returned status_code=|%{http_code}| in %{time_total}s.'" inernalurl")'`

Any suggestion is appreciable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest keep functionalities separate i.e.

1. Let `awk` process text files divided in rows and columns
2. Let `shell` run external utilities on the output of `awk`

You may consider following `awk + xargs` solution:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
internalurl=<internalURL>

awk 'BEGIN {
   FS = OFS = ","
}
NR == FNR {
   map[$1] = $2
   next
}
!($1 in map) || map[$1] != $2 {
   print $1 
}' first.csv second.csv |
xargs -I {} find download -type f -iname '{}' |
curl -F 'file=@-' -O --write-out \
'uploaded %{size_upload} bytes returned status_code=|%{http_code}| in %{time_total}s.' "$internalurl"
```

Comment: anubhava, I tried with -iname '{$1}' as $1 from AWK returns the file name. But does not seems to take up. How would I get a value of $1 and pass on to find command. Sorry for the direct question, I am giving try though.

Comment: never mind! I can store the entire AWK statement to a variable that way I am able to get value from it. However, my requirement is to perform further operations on each instance (file in this case). When I store it as a variable it returns the name of files, I am thinking of converting it into an array and then perform the rest of the operation. If you have any better approach, please do suggest. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Anubhava - Never mind! I used the same approach as you suggested, and indeed it helps in running those commands outside of AWK statement. I'm storing the output of AWK in a variable and being passed in the CURL.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted code is giving an error because you are using `'` inside an `awk` program which is NOT allowed directly, should be used by using a variable or in hex/octal form only inside `awk`'s main program. I am not having full picture what you are trying to achieve(looks to be out of scope of question too) so I am trying to help here how this fix this error, I have made a simple test(file which can have any test line in it) and ran following(this will do a `system` call which has `echo` to print `curl` command as a text on screen for your testing purposes).

```
awk -v s1='\047 -v internalurl=$internalurl 'BEGIN {
   FS = OFS = ","
}
{
   system("echo \"curl -F " s1 "fileData=@$(find download -type f -iname "$1")" s1 " -O --write-out "s1"uploaded %{size_upload} bytes returned status_code=|%{http_code}| in %{time_total}s." s1" internalurl\"")
 
}' Input_file
```

Which will print following `curl` command as follows:

`curl -F 'fileData=@' -O --write-out 'uploaded %{size_upload} bytes returned status_code=|%{http_code}| in %{time_total}s.' internalurl`

You could use above solution to see what's getting printed(because in backend that only will be running, so better check first by printing it either command is correct or not by printing it first) fix your `curl` command errors and once you are happy with it you could then put `system("curl.....")` command to your actual attempted code.

Comment: Ravinder, I'm able to form the expected CURL using ```system("echo \"curl -F FileData=@$(find download -type f -iname "$1") -O --write-out "s1"uploaded %{size_upload} bytes returned status_code=|%{http_code}| in %{time_total}s."s1" "new"\"")```, thank you. However my next challenge is to read the result outside in the shellscript so I can process it further.

Comment: @mansingshinde, I haven't checked it may be you could use ` > outputfile` inside system command itself, make sure you put it inside `"` as this will be considered as a string for `awk`. But if its getting too complex then better to use awk + bash solution suggested by anubhava sir, cheers.

Comment: Thank you, Ravinder for your help, the solution that Anubhava suggested worked for me, I had to tweak it a bit, I am storing the entire AWK in a variable as since in AWS statement I'm outing the $1, the value of that variable becomes the one I was expecting. Thank you again.

Comment: @mansingshinde, your welcome, keep learning and keep posting good q & a cheers

Answer (score 0):

As stated above. The problem is that your `$1` field is not expanded in the `system` function, and `"` quotes are not balanced, and `'` are not balanced as well.

All occurrence of `$1` in the `curl` command need to be replaced with `"$1"`

All the quotes in the `curl` command need to be replaced with `\"`